# Synchronous responses of server for ajax`s requests

Tags: php, ajax, asynchronous

I need to send  ajax's requests to a php's handler. Requests are sending asynchronously but responses are synchronous. I surved the net but didn't found a solution. I know about browser's limits on asynchronous requests.
There is apache on my centos. I think I need to change the server's config but I am not sure of it.
There is a simple example of my situation. In this example I get responses every 5 seconds. How can I solve my problem?
This is the script:

```
for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
    $.get("/ajax1.php",{id:i})
        .done(function (res) {
            if (res != "") {
                $area=$(".workarea-center");
                $area.html($area.html()+res);
            }
        });

}
```

This is the handler.

```
sleep(5);
echo ("111");
```

Comment: just include an id in your request and response, so you can match the response to the request,

Comment: Let me understand your problem. You are expecting all 6 response at the same time but they are comming after and after with 5 seconds intervals?

Comment: You have a `sleep(5)` in your handler and wondering why you get responses every 5th second? What is your actual problem and desired outcome?

Comment: Because of sleep(5) it make your request wait for 5 seconds remove that to get faster result

Comment: I use sleep(5) to do a model of my situation. Reality I don't have this function but every request is handled about 5 seconds. I would like to all requests will handle 5-7 seconds not 30 seconds.

Comment: forcefully you are making it to sleep for 5 seconds that means that is fixed + your code execution time will give you late response time . You have check if your code is taking too much time the remove sleep(5) from it otherwise it will give you late response